# How to change resource in resource_url depending on Model from where it was called?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following code:

```
  def perform(message, slug)
    url = Bitly.client.shorten(post_url(slug)).short_url
    tweet("#{message} #{url}")
  end
```

Lets say I also have a **Book** model(the code above is for Post model). And if I want to get a book url I use the following helper `book_url(slug)`

**How can change post_url to book_url depending on model where perform was called?**

So, if the method was called from Book model, I have book_path if from Post model, I have post_path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can dynamically call those helpers or modelfunctions with the send() method. That method is coming from Ruby, here is more info.
http://apidock.com/ruby/Object/send

In your case you just do it like this:

```
model_name = object.class.to_s.underscore
send("#{model_name}_path", slug)
```

**edit**
as for your code it might be

```
send("#{model_name}_url", slug, host: ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options[:host] )
```

i tried it for you in my console:

```
include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
model_name = User.first.class.to_s.underscore
=> "user"
send("#{model_name}_path", User.first.cached_slug)
=> "/community/user/hummel"
send("#{model_name}_path", User.first.id)
=> "/community/user/1"
```

**as on request**

as you want to send a host to that method use the `_url` instead of `_path` helper and also give the extra param  `host` into the method.

```
send("#{model_name}_url", User.first.cached_slug, host: "google.com")
=>http://google.com/community/user/hummel
```

Comment: I was trying to do something similar "#{model_name}_url"  but it didn't work. Yours solutions works but how can I add host to this code? post_url(slug, host: ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options[:host])

Answer (score 1):

If you use Rails standard routes, like: `resources :books`
you can do the following:

```
def perform(message, resource)
  url = Bitly.client.shorten(url_for(resource)).short_url
  tweet("#{message} #{url}")
end
```

For more info, read about [url_for](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/RoutingUrlFor/url_for)

Comment: hey, i've just tested it but without `url_for`,  `Bitly.client.shorten(resource)` and it worked.